# how to configure multiple conditional queries for firestore in flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, flutter-listview

I am able set two different queries for the firestore database on conditional analysis using ternary operator, but what if I have to use 5 different conditions for the same `stream` to build up the query? How can I do that?

```
                  stream: (query != "" && query != null)
                      ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                       .collection('momos_nv')
                       .orderBy('itemName')
                       .startAt([query])
                       .endAt([query + '\uf8ff']).snapshots()
                      : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("momos_nv").snapshots()
```

Comment: You can use the seperate method and perfom your conditional based operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate method with return type Stream.

```
final CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('employees');

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStream(String query) {
    /// Perform your 5 condition here 
    return collection.snapshots();
  }

stream: getStream(query),
```